# How to do smooth scrolling for lists in Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, animation, scroll

On the iPhone scrolling through lists is animated smoothly. Ignoring the inertia effect (though having it would be cool as well) - how would I go about making a Swing listbox scroll smoothly like that?

There are other examples as well, like browsers, but those use native controls which I cannot use with Swing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `JList` try overwrite `getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle, int, int)` and `getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle, int, int)` to return custom increment .. e.g. 2 pixels instead of default values computed from list entry height.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that this answers your question, but I had a similar issue. My problem was that dragging vertical JScrollPane knob made JList to scroll by blocks instead of by units, that is, the top cell was always displayed in whole except when list was scrolled to the bottom.

Curiously, this happened only when using Windows look and feel. By using default L&F I got the behavior I wanted. And after much digging, I found [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/341550/GUI/java/JList-JScrollPane) which revealed that there is L&F property for that. By default this is true for Windows L&F, but you can set it to false like this:

```
UIManager.put("List.lockToPositionOnScroll", Boolean.FALSE);
```