# Smooth scrolling for JLists like in web browsers

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I wan't smooth scrolling for a JList that shows some search results. With the default unit increment of the vertical scroll bar the scrollling speed is too slow. When increasing the unit increment the scrolling speed is faster but for the user the scrolling looks very abruptly and not very smooth.

Is there any built-in functionality or any other approach that allows smooth scrolling like in web browsers? Every proposed solution I found so far (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999932/how-to-do-smooth-scrolling-for-lists-in-swing)) just increases the unit increment but that's not what I really want (or what a user is likely expecting).

Answer (score 3):

[`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) implements [`Scrollable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getScrollableUnitIncrement%28java.awt.Rectangle,%20int,%20int%29) to achieve this. You can override `getScrollableUnitIncrement()` to return your preferred increment for a given orientation and direction.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but when setting the scrollable unit increment to a small number (e.g. 1) the scrolling is too slow but when using a larger number (e.g. 20) the scrolling is not smooth. What I want is a small unit increment but when using e.g the mouse wheel several units should be scrolled continuously (similar to a web browser).

Comment: As the default key binding may be an alternative, check your host platform's setting for keyboard repeat. As the effect represents a compromise based on platform settings and performance, you might make your application's value a `java.util.Preference`.